# Sql join on similar columns, but not same

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose i have column a in one table and column 2 in another. They are both navchar. Column 2 ends with '-US'. How do I join the two tables, provided that column 1 is the same as 2 but without the us ending?

Comment: `on t2.c2 = t1.c1 + '-US'` You might also try adding `and t2.c2 like t1.c1 + '%'` to see if you get a better/faster plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do either

```
SELECT
    a.Field1
    ,a.Field2
    ,b.Field3
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b
    ON a.Fieldname + '-US' = b.FieldName
```

or if it's not always going to end in -US then you could try this

```
SELECT
    a.Field1
    ,a.Field2
    ,b.Field3
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b
    ON b.FieldName LIKE a.FieldName + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to do is to take the `-US` suffix into account:

```
on t2.c2 = t1.c1 + '-US'
```

or perhaps:

```
on t1.c1 = left(t2.c2, len(t2.c2) - 3)
```

If you want performance, you might consider a computed column with an index.  Something like this:

```
alter table t1 add c1_us as (c1 + '-US');

create index t1_c1_us on t1(c1_us);
```

This would then allow an index to be used for a condition such as:

```
on t2.c2 = t1.c1_us
```